# How to parse a delegate method from a xml file?

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to be able to have a button for my interface that uses different delegates if pressed etc.

And in order to make it easy it would be nice to be able to load the buttons from XML. I already have it setup like this:

```
<EclipseButton name="button1" texkey="thumbnail" istodraw="True">
 <position>
  <x>10</x>
  <y>10</y>
 </position>
 <width>64</width>
 <height>64</height>
</EclipseButton>
```

But I would like to be able to add:

```
<IfPressed>
 <![CDATA[
 Console.WriteLine("The button is pressed");
 ]]>
</IfPressed>
```

And then I can convert the text in cdata as if it were a lambda:

```
() => { Console.WriteLine("The button is pressed"); }
```

Is there anyway to make this possible?

Comment: Please don't prefix your title with "C#" - that's what we have tags for here.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate to @Yahia's response, you can create a list of pre-defined actions (similar to what the [ASP AJAX Control Toolkits](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/UpdatePanelAnimation/UpdatePanelAnimation.aspx) do for actions) and allow the markup to specify order, etc. e.g.

```
<IfPressed>
  <WriteToConsole Text="The button is pressed" />
</IfPressed>
```

Then parse the collection as a to-do list, going through each added item and executing it.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible although not easy - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/650ax5cx.aspx

You would need to compile the code at runtime and use reflection to invoke etc.